# GitHub API - how to move an issue to a project?

Tags: project, github-api

There are several ways to move a Github issue to a Project board through the GitHub user interface, but there doesn't seem to be any way to do this via the API (either v3 or v4). Is this missing functionality?

Comment: There is an API V4 now (June 2023). See [my edited answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57024538/6309).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

2019: You can:

- [create a project card](https://developer.github.com/v3/projects/cards/#create-a-project-card): `POST /projects/columns/:column_id/cards`
- [move a project card](https://developer.github.com/v3/projects/cards/#move-a-project-card): `POST /projects/columns/cards/:card_id/moves`

That is:

- The first one allows you to associate an issue to a project card,

> `content_id`: The issue or pull request id you want to associate with this card. You can use the [List issues for a repository](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#list-issues-for-a-repository) and [List pull requests endpoints](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#list-pull-requests) to find this id.
> Note: Depending on whether you use the issue id or pull request id, you will need to specify `Issue` or `PullRequest` as the `content_type`.

- the second one allows you to move a card (and its associated issue)
- As noted by [Nils](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1528859/nils) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57024087/github-api-how-to-move-an-issue-to-a-project/57024538?noredirect=1#comment136555931_57024538), use the ID of the issue, not the number (which I usually associate with the issue) as `content_id`. Otherwise, it will not work.

Those two calls ought to be enough.

---

The OP [Ken Liu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/25688/ken-liu) asked [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57024087/github-api-how-to-move-an-issue-to-a-project/57024538#comment100589424_57024538) if there is any way to add an issue to a project without adding it to a project column.

[seth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/517662/seth) suggests:

> You can add an issue to the repo using code (GitHub API) as per [creating an issue](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/issues#create-an-issue)

---

2023 (June): since the [GitHub CLI `gh` v2.31.0](https://i), you now have a [`gh project item-add` command](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_project_item-add):

```bash
# add an item to monalisa's project "1"
gh project item-add 1 --owner monalisa --url https://github.com/monalisa/myproject/issues/23
```

Note that, while there is a [project REST API v3](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/projects/projects?apiVersion=2022-11-28), [`pkg/cmd/project/item-add/item_add.go`](https://github.com/cli/cli/blob/ad4a489f8d363ee55fa0401b497ee15f0770487d/pkg/cmd/project/item-add/item_add.go#L118-L125) uses GitHub API v4: GraphQL.

Comment: Thanks -- did you see any way to add an issue to a project without adding it to a project column? This is the default behavior in the UI but it seems like it's not possible with these API methods.

Comment: @KenLiu I agree: I did not see that at first glance.

Comment: You can add an issue to the repo using code as per [creating an issue](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/issues#create-an-issue)

Comment: Thank you for this, the endpoint to create a card containing an issue or a pull request is basically undocumented – specifically, the value of `content_type` is nowhere to be found, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Please use the **id** of the issue, not the number (which I usually associate with the issue) as `content_id`. Otherwise it will not work.

Comment: @Nils Good point, thank you for your feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.