# Add Merged PRs to a Project Using Github Actions

Tags: github-actions

I'm attempting to create an Action that automatically adds a merged PR to a project so the PR can be reviewed for documentation needs. The key here is that the PR should be added to the project *after* it's been merged into `main`. From what I can tell, Github Actions don't work directly with merged PRs for the `pull_request` [webhook](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request).

Has anybody managed to do this or have any tips? My initial thought is to do something like:

```
name: Add-Merged-PRs

# Run this workflow every time a PR is merged into the main branch
on: push
  branches:
    - main

jobs:
  # Take the PR that was merged and add it to a specified project.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `pull_request` event and narrow it down to "has been closed" and "was merged" using the `types` and `branches` properties of `pull_request`, then check in the `github.event.pull_request` context that the `merged` property is `true`.

All together, for a project named "Test" and a column "Merged PRs", using the [GitHub CLI](https://github.com/cli/cli) to make API calls, a workflow might look like this:

```yaml
name: Add merged PRs to project

# When a PR into main is closed or merged
on:
  pull_request:
    types:
      - closed
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  addpr:
    name: Add PR to project

    # PR must must be merged, not closed
    if: github.event.pull_request.merged

    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04

    steps:
      - name: Add PR to project board
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        run: |
          projectid=$(gh api "repos/${{ github.repository }}/projects" \
              -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.inertia-preview+json" \
              | jq '.[] | select(.name == "Test").id')

          columnid=$(gh api "projects/$projectid/columns" \
              -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.inertia-preview+json" \
              | jq '.[] | select(.name == "Merged PRs").id')

          gh api "projects/columns/$columnid/cards" \
              -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.inertia-preview+json" \
              -F "content_type=PullRequest" \
              -F "content_id=${{ github.event.pull_request.id }}"
```

For reference and to see how "closed with unmerged commits" and "properly merged" are told apart, see the [docs for the `pull_request` payload object](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#webhook-payload-object-31).

Comment: Thanks! If I'm following correctly, I would then be able to manipulate the PR object to update the 'project' field?

Comment: @myshortfriend No, you'd have to make an API call to update the project to add that PR, but at a glance, I don't see an endpoint that lets you do that in the [projects API docs](https://git.io/Jteh4) or the [pull request API docs](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/pulls). There is some [built-in automation](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/managing-your-work-on-github/configuring-automation-for-project-boards) for project boards, but it only works for PRs already in the project; I'm not sure if what you're trying to do is currently possible.

Comment: Thanks for checking. I think I might be able to use the [create a project card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57024087/github-api-how-to-move-an-issue-to-a-project) API to get this to work.

Comment: @myshortfriend I think you're right, I was just looking at that. I've been using the GitHub CLI to make API calls out of GitHub Actions, it's pretty convenient, see for example the `gh api` calls in [this action](https://github.com/bewuethr/release-tracker-action/blob/master/tagupdater).

Comment: @myshortfriend Thanks for that pointer to the answer about adding a PR in a card, the API docs aren't very clear about this. I've extended my answer to a full workflow that adds closed PRs to a project board now.