# Move issues in project boards using GitHub actions

Tags: github, github-api, github-actions, github-for-windows, github-issues

I want to create a workflow for moving issues in GitHub project boards such as:

1. When someone creates an issue it moves to the project board "To do".
2. Once the developer creates a branch with issue name then the issue should move to the different project board "In Progress"
3. Once the developer finished his work and merge it with the master branch then it should move to project board "Done"

I got some workflow for creating a branch for issues and move-in boards but I am unable to create the flow.

Answer (score 0):

**Github API**

There is a full [project section](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/projects) in the Github API with endpoints you could use to customize your workflows.

*Note: [here is a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57024087/github-api-how-to-move-an-issue-to-a-project)*

**Github Actions**

There is also a [Github automate project action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/automate-projects) on the Github marketplace, to use directly in your workflow if it match your context.

*Note: There may be others on the [github marketplace](https://github.com/marketplace?type=actions&query=project+)*

Comment: Thanks for the help with the above points. I am able to move issues on project boards but still not able to find a way to compare the created branch with issues name and move issue in progress board which is my 2nd point.